# Linq where on a entity list property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, nhibernate

this is my scenario.
I have three entities: Dealer, Car, Engines .
They are linked so that a dealer can have one or more car model with different engines.

```
public class Dealer
{
  public virtual int id{get;set;}
  public virtual string name{get;set;}
  public virtual IList<Car> Cars{get;set;}
}

public class Car 
{
  public virtual int id{get;set;}
  public virtual string name{get;set;}
  public virtual Engine engine{get;set;}
}

public class Engine
{
  public virtual int id{get;set;}
  public virtual string description{get;set;}
  public virtual int kw{get;set;}
}
```

Example: I need to find all Dealer that have car(s) with an 98kw engine.

I tried with (I know it is wrong..):

```
var out = Session.Linq<Dealer>().Where("Cars.Engine.Kw == 98").ToList();
```

**In which way could I get what I need?**

Comment: And Owner==Dealer ??  Please check your code before posting. Best to make it compile first.

Comment: Excuse me sir.. Fixed it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically,

```
var dealers = Session.Linq<Dealer>().Where(d => d.Cars.Any(c => c.Engine.Kw == 98 ));
```

but this will of course explode when a Car has no Engine.

Comment: Hey @Henk, would be nice if you could include a little more explanation or narrative in your answer next time!